# RESTFULL codeigniter api configured and not working

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-3

Have included rest.php in config folder,

have added the library files in the library folder.

codeigniter version is ok and 3 or above

php version ok and 5.4 of above

my controller:

```
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Books_api extends REST_Controller {

  public function book_get()
  {
    // Display all books
    $this->response(array('data'=> 'test'), 200);
  }

  public function book_post()
  {
    // Create a new book
  }
}
```

my api call:

```
http://localhost/project_name/index.php/books_api/book
method I tried is GET from postman or httpRequester
```

my response header

```
 -- response --
404 Not Found
Date:  Mon, 04 Apr 2016 14:12:56 GMT
Server:  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:  PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Content-Length:  1130
Keep-Alive:  timeout=5, max=100
Connection:  Keep-Alive
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Am I doing any mistake here ? may be but I could not figure it out.
Please help me out.

Comment: File name is ucfirst i.e. `Books_api.php`?

Comment: If you visit the URL in your web browser then it fails as well?

Comment: @Tpojka - no its books_api.php

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - yes.

Comment: Have you changed your filename to `Books_api.php` as suggested by Tpojka? Also, make sure your controller looks like this `class Books_api extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - are sure I need to make the class `class Books_api extends CI_Controller {`  ? As in the turorial or in the documentation it says I need to use like  `class Books_api extends REST_Controller {` - can you send me your sample code that is working for you ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - earlier my file name was `books_api.php` and now its `Books_api.php` both fails to work.

Comment: Its now `Books_api.php` and `class Books_api extends REST_Controller {` and it shows some error saying  `Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/rest_controller_lang.php`

Comment: I downloaded the lang file and all fixed, get working now. Thanks for your time and comments. was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I see the file name should be `Books_api.php` and not `books_api.php`.

May be a silly mistake, but should be useful for rest starters.